# Automatic weights not working well

Tags: armature, bones, weight-painting

I'm new to blender and following a tutorial. I finished rigging and set parent with automatic weights but for some reason it doesn't work well for me - the side of the body of the mesh moves when I move the IK_Hand in pose mode.
In the tutorial it moves good and only the hand and its relevant parts are moving.

Can you help me with this?

This is my file: [Mushroom](http://www.mediafire.com/file/cphazrdysk2rydg/Mushroom.blend/file)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your normals are flipped, you can see it if you enable *Face Orientation* in the *Viewport Overlays* options, it messes up the parentage. Go in *Edit* mode, select all and *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside*, or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>. Then reparent *With Automatic Weight*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain why this happened? and a little bit of what it means?

Comment: Faces have 2 sides, on one side you have normals. Normals have different purposes in 3D realm, it mainly show the face orientation. When you model an object, Blender doesn't know on what side you want normals, so you go on and they might point towards the object's inside. It might cause problem like the one you've encountered and other various problems. So sometimes check the faces normal.